# QTreeView : get a list of the items highlighted only (Multiple selection)

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, multipleselection, getdirectories

I would like to get the folder pathes of a multiple selection. I wish to get only the ones that are highlighted when clicking. Ideally, a list would be updated interactively. I mean, if one folder is deselected, it is automatically removed from the list.

Here an example of QTreeView below ... Can you provide support please?

Thank you

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(1150, 905)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.groupBox     = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout   = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.treeView     = QtGui.QTreeView(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.AllEntries)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(True)
        self.root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath('/home/')
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.root)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `selectedIndexes()` method of [QItemSelectionModel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(1150, 905)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.groupBox     = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout   = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.treeView     = QtGui.QTreeView(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | 
            QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.AllEntries)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(True)
        self.root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath('/home/')
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.root)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
        self.treeView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.getItems)


    def getItems(self):
        selected = self.treeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected:
            if index.column() == 0:
                print self.fileSystemModel.data(index,
                    self.fileSystemModel.FileNameRole).toString()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```